# router-view and component in vue app (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to have a router-view and component in my Laravel blade file. The  `router-view` works perfectly and it changes component based on the page URL. However I want to add a `<nav></nav>` component above my `router-view` so that I can load in the navigation on each page.

My question is, what is wrong? It doesn't work, currently the `<router-view>` loads the correct components, however the `<nav>` does not load anything in.

**App.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import {routes} from './routes';
import Nav from './components/Nav.vue';
import store from './store.js';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    components: {
        Nav
    }
});
```

**Master.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app">
        <nav></nav>

        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Nav.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>hey</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "nav"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: @Joe My question is, what is wrong? It doesn't work, currently the `<router-view>` loads the correct components, however the `<nav>` does not load anything in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a different name for the component, other than `nav` since it's a valid HTML reserved tag.

Comment: Great it works perfectly thanks. I feel a bit stupid now.

Comment: Nothing to worry, it happens all the time!